# JavaScript event calendar (FullCalendar) StartDate EndDate formating Issue on the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using  JavaScript event calendar. Everything is working fine except start and end date displaying problem. I am reading Data from SQL server and format is SD:2017-12-08 12:30:00 and ED:2017-12-08 16:30:00. But on the browser event shows as 12-08-2017. Same thin happens to all the events.

```html
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("EventList.aspx/GetEvents")%>',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#fullcal').fullCalendar({
                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        $('#eid').html(calEvent.id);
                        $('#modalTitle').html(calEvent.title);
                        $('#msDate').html(moment(calEvent.start).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));
                        $('#meDate').html(moment(calEvent.end).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));
                        $('#mloc').html(calEvent.loc)
                        $('#mdesc').html(calEvent.des)
                        $('#url').attr('href', 'Meetings/Meeting.aspx?ID=' + calEvent.id)
                        $('#fullCalModal').modal();

                    },

                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',

                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                    },
                    views: {
                        month: { // name of view

                            columnFormat: 'dddd',

                        },


                        week: { // name of view
                            titleFormat: 'MMMM  D , YYYY',
                            columnFormat: 'dddd D/M',

                        },
                        day: { // name of view
                            titleFormat: 'MMMM  DD  YYYY',
                            columnFormat: 'dddd D-M-YYYY',

                        }
                    },

                    //editable: true,
                    displayEventTime: false,// hide event time 
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    events: $.map(data.d, function (item, i) {
                        var event = new Object();
                        event.id = item.EventID;
                        event.title = item.EventName;
                        event.start = new Date(moment(item.StartDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));
                        event.end = new Date(moment(item.EndDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'));
                        event.loc = item.Location;
                        event.des = item.Description;
                        return event;
                    }),

                });

                $("div[id=fullcal]").show();

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your events section specifically says :  `event.start = ... format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm') ...`, and the same for end date...

Comment: What changes i have to make on this ?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding - what is your *desired* date format? Perhaps try `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm`?

Comment: Events are not displaying in IE browser if I try with event.start = new Date(moment(item.StartDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select your StartDate & EndDate using ISO 8601 format from SQL server Database: CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),starttime, 126) as startdate  which returns 2017-12-08T12:30:00